# Why wont my program output numbers

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I need help to make my program output **50** random numbers between **45** and **-5**. I dont know why its not outputting. It must use arrays. It should also be displayed in **5** columns.

MY CODE:

```
int randnum[]=new int[50];
    for(int i=0;i<=50;i++)
        randnum[i]=(int)(Math.random()*(45+5))-5;
        System.out.println(randnum[i]+"");
```

Comment: Should probaly be: `if(i==5)`

Answer (score 4):

**First** you missed a brace like @Reimeus said.
**Second** you do not compare `i` with `5`, you try to assign `i` with `5`.

Your code should look like:

```
int randnum[]=new int[50];
for(int i=0; i<50; i++) { // <--- add { here & delete = in condition
    randnum[i]=(int)(Math.random()*(45+5))-5;
    if(i % 5 == 0) { // <--- add a = here & a modulo operator for 5 columns
        System.out.println("");
    }
    System.out.print(randnum[i]+" "); // <--- set your print down here
} // <--- add } here
```

**Update #1:**
Your array has exactly `50` indices, from `0` to `49`. **But** your `for loop` iterates from `0` to `50`, one step to far. So you should run `i < 50` here, else you will run out of bounds.

Else you will get something like this here:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 50
```

**Update #2:**
I added another `if` - statement condition and set your `print` a row above this statement, to serve your wish to post in **5 columns**.

Comment: You forgot `// <--- add a } here` on the last line.

Comment: It doesn't make 5 colums and rows

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a opening brace to your `for` statement which means that the `println` statement is outside the scope of the loop. Also you're using an assignment in your if statement. You need to use the `==` operator to perform integer comparison.

Arrays are zero-based: use the arrays `length` property to avoid the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` that is currently occurring:

Lastly, you can you the modulo operator to pretty-print the values into columns:

```
int randnum[] = new int[50];
for (int i = 0; i < randnum.length; i++) {
    randnum[i] = (int) (Math.random() * (45 + 5)) - 5;
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.print(randnum[i] + "\t"); 
}
```

Read: [Summary of Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)

Comment: He's missing a closing brace too.  The closing brace you're seeing is from the problematic `if(i=5){` line.

Comment: Of course that should be there but the OP may not have neglected to included that in the question...

Answer (score 0):

You must be careful with the brackets:

```
int randnum[]=new int[50];
for(int i=0;i<=50;i++)
{
    randnum[i]=(int)(Math.random()*(45+5))-5;
    System.out.println(randnum[i]+"");
    if(i==5)
        System.out.println("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have the opening brace for the for statement. Also you need to do "if(i==5)" not "if(i=5)".
So it should be:

```
int randnum[]=new int[50];
for(int i=0;i<=50;i++){
randnum[i]=(int)(Math.random()*(45+5))-5;
System.out.println(randnum[i]+"");
if(i==5){
System.out.println("\n");
}
}
```